# VSCode MakeFile tool configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile

I am trying to use [MakeFile Tool](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.makefile-tools) to run makefiles in VSCode. When trying to set the configuration to Default, it says "No configurations defined in makefile.configurations setting."
here is what the settings.json looks like.

```
{
    "omnisharp.path": "latest",
    "makefile.makePath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GnuWin32\\bin\\make",
    "makefile.launchConfigurations": [

    ],
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sharing relevant properties from *.vscode/settings.json*:

```
{
    "makefile.configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Default",
            "makeArgs": []
        }
    ],
    "makefile.launchConfigurations": [
        {
            "cwd": FULL_PATH_O_EXECUTABLE_DIR,
            "binaryPath": FULL_PATH_O_EXECUTABLE_FILE,
            "binaryArgs": []
        }
    ],
    "makefile.buildLog": "",
    "makefile.loggingLevel": "Normal"
}
```

These are basic settings for Makefile Tools extension created by default through vscode.

Now, while having *./Makefile* in the project main directory, the extension should determine the file automatically, and you can see it associated with the file in the extension sidebar, under "Makefile" section. Additionally, the "Launch target" section also should be associated with your executable file path.

When all of those have been set, you can just build the project through the extension sidebar button (at the top, play icon).

Answer (score 1):

you need to add something like this to this settings file.

```
    "makefile.configurations": [
    {
        "name": "myconf",
        "buildLog": "",
        "makeArgs": [],
        "makeDirectory": "",
        "makefilePath": "",
        "makePath": "",
        "problemMatchers": []
    },
]
```

Don't forget to fill those "" with the your settigns